# Asterisk quits intermittently

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, linphone-sdk

I have been working on a project which requires Asterisk as SIP proxy. I am able to register, call and recieve calls with the my setup of asterisk.

Only problem is that Asterisk quits intermittently without any crash dumps or segregation fault nothing!. Also I found that as there's not any reachable users it quits. On restarting i see messages for last qualify 0 for user last reached.

Pretty much stuck on this issue, any help would be much appreciated.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asterisk is not PROXY, it is pbx.

For proxy(load over 1k calls or CPS over 80) please use kamailio.

You have enable core dump and compile asterisk with debug flags to do debugging.

You also may consider change pjsip to chan_sip or via versa.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Getting+a+Backtrace

Comment: I haven't tried above but I am able to see logs and verbose messages as it occurs. The problem is it does'nt crash it just quits from cli  and kills itself.

Comment: I don't know what to do. You have ENABLE dump. Which is clearly stated at link above.

Answer (score 0):

Core dumps must be manually enabled: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Getting+a+Backtrace

Then you can dubug the problem using:

`` gdb `which asterisk` /tmp/core* ``

Then type **bt full** to show all threads.